# codename one picker not selecting

Tags: java, codenameone, picker

I run the following codenameone code in a blank project and it "run"'s in the simulator and selects properly.

Then I "build" the project, or refresh the cn1 libraries and after the successful build, it runs in the simulator, but will not select elements.

This is happening after the xml files are rebuilt by either building the project, refreshing the cn1 libraries, or generating a certificate for Windows.

Netbeans 8.2,
Simulator, 
Windows Desktop 1803,
Windows Phone 14393,
Windows Phone 15063,
Codename One 4.0.3,
jdk 8

The picker selects normally when sent to Android Phone.

I was not having this problem a year ago.

```
    Form f = new Form("Picker", BoxLayout.y());
    Picker p = new Picker();
    p.setType(PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    String[] s = {"1", "2", "3"};
    p.setStrings(s);
    f.add(p);
    f.show();
```

Comment: it certainly looks like it might be a build issue with dependencies, but for the purpose of clarification, what happens if you try adding the setSelectedString( ... )?

Comment: I just tried this and couldn't reproduce it. In your Versions.properties file (in the project itself) what are the library versions? If you don't have a Versions.properties what's your version of the Codename One plugin?

Comment: NOTE: the picker selects normally when executing on Android phone. It is on the simulator and on a Windows Phone that it fails to select. I uninstalled netbeans 8.2 and installed 8.1.  I am using codename one 4.0.3.  Picker still fails to select.

Comment: I am using jdk8 in program files now.  When I allowed netbeans to install the jdk originally, picker would run and select before I updated the cn1 libs.  Now it does not.  Am I using the correct jdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Project Libraries:

Right click project ->  Codenameone -> Codenameone Settings -> Basics -> Update Projects Libs

(Update Project Libs button is bottom left hand side of page).

NOTE: the new picker may be slow responding on UWP phone devices. See

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2478

NOTE: the new picker works well with UWP phone device as of 7/27/2018 codenameone library update.